# How do I find the indices of a given array A1, *any* of whose values are practically equivalent to *any* of the values of a second array A2?

Tags: arrays, matlab

By "practically equivalent", I mean that their distances are of order epsilon apart (or 0.000001). Equality in MATLAB often doesn't really work for long floating numbers.

If I simply do abs(A1 - A2) < 0.000001, it's not going to work since size(A1) != size(A2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the answer by calculating distance between two vectors using MATLAB's `pdist2` function.

```
dist=pdist2(A1,A2);
minDist=min(dist,[],2);
indices_A1=minDist<=0.000001;
desired_A1=A1(indices_A1);
```

Not tested, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you care about a distance from any element to any element, you can create a distance matrix from the vectorized matrices and probe that for the distance threshold. Example:

```
A = rand(10, 4); % (example) matrix A 
B = rand(3, 5);  % matrix B of different size 
minDist = 0.005;
```

**Solution**: Repeat vectorized matrices, column- and row-wise to get same size matrices and apply matrix-based distance estimation:

```
Da = repmat(A(:), 1, length(B(:)));  % size 40 x 15
Db = repmat(B(:)', length(A(:)), 1); % size 40 x 15 
DD = Da - Db; 
indA = any(abs(DD) < minDist, 2);
```

The use of `any()` will give you logical indices to any value of `A` that is close to any value of `B`). You can directly index/return the elements of `A` using `indA.`

The matrix DD (as @Shai also points out) can be equivalently estimated through `bsxfun`

```
DD = bsxfun(@minus, A(:), B(:)');
```

**In addition**: you can map from row-index (corresponding to A elements) back to matrix A indices using:

```
[iA, jA] = ind2sub(size(A), indA);
```

**Assert/test** that all the returned values are less than `minDist`,e.g. using:

```
for k = 1:length(iA); 
    d(k) = min(min(abs(A(iA(k), jA(k)) - B)));
end
all(d < minDist)
```

*(tested in Octave 3.6.2)*

Comment: @Shai I strongly disagree. Taking advantage of vectorization and matrix computations is core MATLAB! No for-loops, no high-level wrappers. Plus, from an algorithm perspective, this gives you all distances on a 2D array. (Note: the loop is for assertion, the solution is 2 calls to repmat and a matrix subtraction).

Comment: Respectfully, I wish to disagree with your disagreement. Using `bsxfun` makes both `repmat` and the loop redundant.  
`[ia1 ia2] = find( abs( bsxfun( @minus, A1(:), A2(:)' ) ) < minDist );`  
Now `ia1` are _linear_ indices into `A1` of all the practically equivalent entries. These can be converted to row/col indices using `[r1 c1] = ind2sub( size(A1), ia1 );`

Comment: As for the loop: `d = min( abs( bsxfun( @minus, A1(ia1), A2(:) ) ), [], 2 );` and  `all(d < minDist)`

Comment: @Shai point made for `bsxfun`. I updated my answer to reflect this as an alternative (vs. the use of repmat), keeping in mind efficiency issues (depending on matrix sizes). Feel free to post all different choices as a new answer.