# MatLab - Compare different size matrix AND allow tolerance, how?

Tags: matlab, matrix

compare different size matrices:     ismember(matrix1,matrix2)

find tolerance: tolerance = 10.1;
                index = abs(matrix1-matrix2) <= tolerance;

I cant get them to work together. How do i implement both together?

I want to not only compare different size matrices but compare them with a tolerance allowing not exact results to be matched.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081215/how-do-i-find-the-indices-of-a-given-array-a1-any-of-whose-values-are-practic/15081259#15081259) question would surely help.

Comment: Describe more, it is not clear.

Comment: ill-defined problem. You want indices or true/false?