# Matlab to Octave: intersect function with tolerance using 'rows' option for large matrices of unequal size AKA ismembertol for Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I am working with two matrices, M and N, where matrix M is 20154x169 and matrix N is 20183x169.  The first two columns of both M and N are x,y coordinates, and the rest of the columns are measurements of a physical property that were collected at each of these coordinates.  As an analogy, I defined two arbitrary matrices, A and B, as

```
A=[0,0.1,0.2,13,0,0.1,0.2,0,0.1,0.2;0,0,0,9,2,2,2,4,4,4]';
B=[12,200,45,92,0.1,0.2,14,0,0.1,0.2,0,0.1,0.21;0,3,0,0,0,0,6,2,2,2,4,4,4]';
```

and I'd like to do either intersect with the rows option:

```
[C,iA_xy,iB_xy]=intersect(A_xy(:,1:2),B_xy(:,1:2),'rows');
```

or use ismember, with a tolerance so that the coordinates (0.21,4) and (0.2,4) are identified as being the same.

Ideally, I would take advantage of Matlab's new ismembertol command, but I'm working with Octave.  I've searched for alternatives, and the closest I've found is the bsxfun solution posted as an answer to the question [posed by InquilineKea in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081215/how-do-i-find-the-indices-of-a-given-array-a1-any-of-whose-values-are-practic/15081259#15081259), namely,

```
tol=0.01;
Ax=bsxfun(@minus,B(:),A(:)');
indA=any(abs(Ax)<tol,1);
[rA,cA]=ind2sub(size(A),indA);
```

but this isn't a row-by-row solution equivalent to using the 'rows' option in ismember or intersect and it indicates that first row (0,0) in matrix A is common in matrix B because the x-coordinate 0 appears elsewhere in B, but the entire row isn't in both.  Is there another good, simple way to pick out all similar (x,y) pairs in two matrices within a tolerance and identify their row position, especially for big matrices? Have I missed an obvious extension of this solution to my problem? Does anyone have insight into the mechanisms of the Matlab ismembertol function?

Comment: What would the result be for the proposed example, exactly? Which output of `ismember` (with tolerance) would you want?

Comment: Ideally, the result for `indA = ismember(A,B,'rows');` would be indA = 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1, and `indB = ismember(B,A, 'rows');` would then give indB = 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1.  The bsxfun solution listed above gives rA = 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10, so the x-value in the 10th pair is identified as being within tolerance but the first pair is also identified as being within B (which it isn't.) I would be interested in what, I suppose, would be intersecttol since it will take an extra step to identify the 1's in the ismember function output, but will take whatever I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want (in Matlab). It corresponds to `ind = ismember(A,B,'rows')` with a tolerance `tol`.

```
ind = any(squeeze(all(abs(bsxfun(@minus, B, permute(A, [3 2 1]))) <= tol, 2)), 1);
```

(Of course, for `ind = ismember(B,A,'rows')` with a tolerance just swap `A` and `B` in the above code).

Comment: This works perfectly for my test matrices!  Appreciate the help VERY much, as it was going on hour five of trying new things and having eyeballs glaze over..

Comment: Ah, one last thought:  when adapting this solution to my very large matrices, I run into the "out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type" error.  I'll try to determine where the memory hangup is on my end.

Comment: I don't use Octave, so I can't be of much help there :-) But `bsxfun` builds a `numel(A)`x`numel(B)` matrix, so it can be memory intensive

Comment: Thanks for the bsxfun insight - I thought that was the way it worked, but I think I also have a good workaround for my particular case!